# Apache Rule to Create Cookie

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm struggling to understand how to get a rewrite rule to work for Apache.  There's a header with a JWT and I want to have Apache take the JWT and make it a cookie.

I've tried

RewriteRule .* -[E=X-Amzn-Oidc-Access-Token:%{REQ:X-Amzn-Oidc-Access-Token}]

and also

SetEnvIf X-Amzn-Oidc-Accesstoken "(.*)" TEST_VALUE=$1
RewriteRule .* - [CO=cookiename:%{TEST_VALUE}e:/:60:1]

What I haven't been able to get is just a single cookie to get made.

If I do Header add Set-Cookie %{TEST_VALUE}e I get a cookie with the correct value, but regardless of what I do I can't change any of the other attributes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

how about not using rewrite rules but just:

```
Header add Set-Cookie %{HTTP:X-Amzn-Oidc-Access-Token}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had started with that and was able to get it create a cookie that had the appropriate value.  The issue I was running into though was setting any of the other attributes for the cookie like HTTP only, secure, etc...  I couldn't find a straightforward answer on how do that.

Comment: you could add ";HttpOnly;Secure" so it'd become: Header add Set-Cookie %{HTTP:X-Amzn-Oidc-Access-Token};HttpOnly;Secure